# Get random ID from DB on button click

Tags: c#, mysql, razor, model-view-controller, lambda

Hi guys (I'm a beginner so take it easy) I have this code which searches my database and brings up the title / artists and that works fine. I am required to make a button which when clicked it brings up a random ID from my database. I have looked around but can't find anything useful.Trying to come up with a lamda expression or something...
Thanks

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Play(string searchTitle, string searchArtist, string shuffle)
{
    var media = from s in db.UploadTables select s;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTitle))
    {
        media = media.Where(m => m.MediaTitle.Contains(searchTitle));
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchArtist))
    {
        media = media.Where(m => m.MediaArtist.Contains(searchArtist));
    }

    return View(media);
}
```

VIEW

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Song Name: @Html.TextBox("searchTitle")    
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        Artist: @Html.TextBox("searchArtist")    
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        @Html.TextBox("shuffle")    
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
    <hr />
}
```

Comment: You could get a random number between `0` and `db.UploadTables.Count()`, then use `db.UploadTables.Skip(random).First()` maybe?

Comment: this sounds like homework so i dont want to post a full answer.

why not select by id where id pass a random number? javascript math can help you select a random number?

alternatively select all again generate a random number and take that number from the index? the second would be more resource intensive based on the size on the db, the first also has some issue depending on the number you select and the size of the DB but you need to think what that might be.

Comment: You could also just grab all the IDs in the db store them in a list, and randomly select an item out of the list.

@Rafalon My solution is related to your comment but I'm assuming that the OP's IDs aren't sequential.

Comment: @user618509 the question is not if it is homework or not. As soon as OP made an attempt, it doesn't matter if it is homework or not.

Comment: No @user618509 and @Bmoe the most easy way In MySQL to get a random ID is. `SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random rand = new Random();
int total = db.UploadTables.Count();
var randomId = db.UploadTables.Skip(rand.Next(total)).First().Id;
```

[`Random.Next(Int32 maxValue)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/zd1bc8e5(v=vs.110).aspx) will get a number between `0` and `maxValue-1`.

[`IQueryable<TSource>.Skip(this IQueryable<TSource>, int count)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/bb357513(v=vs.110).aspx) will skip `count` entries.

You then take the `First()` of the remaining entries and **tadaa** you can access its `Id` field.

Obviously, this is only one way to do it, and as told by others, there are many ways to do that.